# VBA to Pull equal value from different location

Tags: vba

This is what I am currently trying to achieve in this project. The scenario, I have identified an item with zero inventory at a location color yellow, I need to search for the network of locations (data is pulled from the main data source) for the same item, category but I don’t want to see the yellow location because I already know yellow has zero inventory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9QBw.png)

Comment: This doesn’t make a lot of sense and there’s no question here

Comment: Sorry if this confused you, if you're able to click the image you will find the picture attached to clarify the problem.

Comment: I am trying to pull inventory record from my data source (Sheet2). I have thousands of unique parts that are categorized in groups, stored in hundreds of locations. Instead of doing a pivot, I would like a to create a VBA that can pull the different parts under the same group category in all locations except the location I already know that has zero inventory. It would be a For Loop but the create the exception is my problem.

Comment: I see the picture but even with it an the explanations you’ve given I don’t know where to start regarding advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raj i m not sure what to you mean but i try to create a code.

Sheet 1

[image]

1. Structure include the search engine (yellow area) and the results)
2. You just import data on the yellow fields
3. where the code run erase the results to bring the new ones.

Sheet 2

[image]

Structure (include the Data Base)

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Mat_Cat_Loc As String
    Dim LastRow1 As Long

    With Sheet1

        If .Range("B2").Value = "" Or .Range("B3").Value = "" Or .Range("B4").Value = "" Then '<= if some search part missing end sub
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Mat_Cat_Loc = .Range("B2").Value & .Range("B3").Value & .Range("B4").Value ' <= Create Mat_Cat_Loc for the search product

        LastRow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A8:D" & LastRow1).Clear '<= Clear range from the previous search

    End With

    With Sheet2

        LastRow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 3 To LastRow2 ' <= Loop in Sheet2 and if Mat_Cat_Loc (From the search) does not match Mat_Cat_Loc (From the data does not copy the line to Sheet1 Rsult Table)
            If (.Range("D" & i).Value <> Mat_Cat_Loc) And (.Range("C" & i).Value) <> Sheet1.Range("B4").Value Then
                With Sheet1
                    LastRow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("A" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value
                    .Range("B" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value
                    .Range("C" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value
                    .Range("D" & LastRow1 + 1).Value = Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```